# Dart/Flutter packages conflict

Tags: dictionary, dart, flutter

I try to implement this map in my flutter application:
https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_map

If I run example code from github above, it throws such an error:

```
type 'Bounds<num>' is not a subtype of type 'Bounds<double>' where
Bounds is from package:flutter_map/src/core/bounds.dart
num is from dart:core
Bounds is from package:flutter_map/src/core/bounds.dart
double is from dart:core
```

My imports:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the day this was posted, flutter_map was not updated to support the more robust type system in dart 2.0. It does work with dart 1.0.

As of 4/18/2018, version 0.0.3 of flutter_map has been released and according to [the changelog](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map/versions/0.0.3#-changelog-tab-) fixes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that `flutter_map` is broken, and should be reported to the author, because yes, num is not a subtype of double.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my configuration or dependencies, flutter_map works for everyone else

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart' as mp;
```

Comment: You should elaborate on how/why this would be a solution.

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer